# Navigate from Java Activity to A composable function

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, composable

I have a Java class that I want to navigate and pass data to composable function(another page). Can I use Intent and putExtra to do this?

Comment: sure. But it depends how you created navigation and the composable function. You can also consider DataStore or Room Instead.

Comment: @c-an can you help me on how to do that?

Comment: Well, just save the data through viewModel before moving to the next page. And then get the data from repository.